# Unexpected UI Behavior

Tags: java, android-recyclerview

Am developing using a Pluralsight Course, "Enhancing the Android Application Experience" as a guide but because of the changes to Android some of the methods no longer apply. After implementing the Java code as instructed, when I selected the course Item on the Navigation Drawer it still displays the same content as the note Item. Please help out

I have tried to correct it using documentation and other posts on Navigation Drawer here @Stack overflow but no luck

```
        mNoteLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mCoursesLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);

        List<NoteInfo> notes = DataManager.getInstance().getNotes();
        mNoteRecyclerAdapter = new NoteRecyclerAdapter(this, notes);

        List<CourseInfo> courses = DataManager.getInstance().getCourses();
        mCourseRecyclerAdapter = new CourseRecyclerAdapter(this, courses);
        displayNotes();

 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_notes) {
            displayNotes();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_courses) {
            displayCourses();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            handleSelection("Don't you think you've shared enough");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
            handleSelection("Send");
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoteActivity.class));
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_notes, R.id.nav_courses, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        initializeDisplayContent();
    }
```

The Course Item Should display course while the note displays course and note titles

```
    private final Context mContext;
    private final List<NoteInfo> mNotes;
    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public NoteRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<NoteInfo> notes) {
        mContext = context;
        mNotes = notes;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_note_list, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NoteInfo note = mNotes.get(position);
        holder.mTextCourse.setText(note.getCourse().getTitle());
        holder.mTextTitle.setText(note.getTitle());
        holder.mCurrentPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNotes.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public final TextView mTextCourse;
        public final TextView mTextTitle;
        public int mCurrentPosition;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextCourse = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_course);
            mTextTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NoteActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(NoteActivity.NOTE_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class CourseRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CourseRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final List<CourseInfo> mCourses;
    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public CourseRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<CourseInfo> courses) {
        mContext = context;
        mCourses = courses;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_course_list, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CourseInfo course = mCourses.get(position);
        holder.mTextCourse.setText(course.getTitle());
        holder.mCurrentPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCourses.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public final TextView mTextCourse;
        public int mCurrentPosition;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextCourse = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_course);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, mCourses.get(mCurrentPosition).getTitle(),
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are calling same function 'displayNotes()' on both click event, nav_courses and nav_share. Distinguish it by adding parameter on function call.

Comment: I have applied the function call difference but the result is unchanged

Comment: you need to add all code here, for better understanding.

Comment: I have included the NoteRecyclerAdapter and CourseRecyclerAdapter class in the code to enable assistance. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things to take a look at:

I don't see any code that sets the activity as the navigation item selected listener for the navigation view:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Also be sure to checkout the order of the content in the activity_main.xml file. There's a bug in Android Studio 3.5 that creates that file with the NavitationView and include entries in the incorrect order. The include entry needs to appear before (i.e. above) the NavigationView entry.

As a side note, I'm in the midst of updating the course to reflect the changes in Android Studio and will have it published shortly.

Comment: wow, the UI behavior is now as expected, thank you so much Sir